# Unable to use Qt + DXFLib

Tags: qt, dxf

I'm going to use [dxflib](http://www.ribbonsoft.com/en/what-is-dxflib) in my Qt application. Build process is OK but when I'm going to run it, the application stops working at the beginning with this error :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x776415de in DXFOpen.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
```

Here is my simple app :

```
class CreatorAdaptor : public DL_CreationAdapter
{
    QGraphicsScene *_scene;
public:
    explicit CreatorAdaptor(QGraphicsScene *scene);
    virtual void addLine(const DL_LineData &d);
    virtual void addLayer(const DL_LayerData& data);
    virtual void addPoint(const DL_PointData& data);
    virtual void addArc(const DL_ArcData& data);
    virtual void addCircle(const DL_CircleData& data);
    virtual void addPolyline(const DL_PolylineData& data);
    virtual void addVertex(const DL_VertexData& data);
    virtual void add3dFace(const DL_3dFaceData& data);


};
```

And the definition of the class :

```
CreatorAdaptor::CreatorAdaptor(QGraphicsScene *scene) :_scene(scene)
{
}

void CreatorAdaptor::addLine(const DL_LineData &d)
{
    qDebug()<<"add line";
    _scene->addLine(d.x1, d.y1, d.x2, d.y2);
}
...
```

Here is my main :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView  *view = new QGraphicsView;
    QGraphicsScene  * scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    view->setScene(scene);
    CreatorAdaptor *dxfscene = new CreatorAdaptor(scene);
    DL_Dxf dxf;
     if(dxf.in("demo.dxf", dxfscene))
         QMessageBox::warning(0,"error", "error");
    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Call Stack :

```
    ntdll.dll!77af15de()    
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!77af15de()    
    ntdll.dll!77ae014e()    
    kernel32.dll!755e14dd()     
>   msvcr100d.dll!_free_base(void * pBlock)  Line 50 + 0x13 bytes   C
    0041f648()  
    QtCored4.dll!qFree(void * ptr)  Line 60 + 0xa bytes C++
    QtCored4.dll!QVectorData::free(QVectorData * x, int alignment)  Line 82 + 0x9 bytes C++
    QtCored4.dll!QVectorTypedData<char *>::free(QVectorTypedData<char *> * x, int alignment)  Line 99 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QVector<char *>::free(QVectorTypedData<char *> * x)  Line 468 + 0x12 bytes C++
    QtCored4.dll!QVector<char *>::~QVector<char *>()  Line 124 + 0x30 bytes C++
    QtCored4.dll!qWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * instance, HINSTANCE__ * prevInstance, char * cmdParam, int cmdShow, int & argc, QVector<char *> & argv)  Line 193   C++
    0041f7e0()  
    DXFOpen.exe!__security_init_cookie()  Line 143  C
    DXFOpen.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()  Line 371   C
    kernel32.dll!755e339a()     
    ntdll.dll!77b09ef2()    
    ntdll.dll!77b09ec5()
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, see [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-debugging-example.html) for debugging with Qt Creator.

Comment: @sashoalm ~> Are you joking ?! Application doesn't start at all ! Even debugging stops!

Comment: I am not joking. Did you run your program under a debugger before posting this question?

Comment: Sure ! I'm a programmer like you! :D

Comment: OK, on which line did you get the unhandled exception?

Comment: The DXF part of code works perfectly outside of a Qt application.

Comment: @sashoalm~> wait a moment !

Comment: in **qWinMain** function at line `argv = qWinCmdLine<char>(cmdParam, int(strlen(cmdParam)), argc);appCmdShow = cmdShow;` . As I said it's not a regular expection!

Comment: What is the entire call stack, all the functions that were called.

Comment: "too long by 262 characters" Stackoverflow said ! :D . May I send the project to your mail pls ?! It doesn't depend on any external lib! Then post the solution here and I'll accept it :D .

Comment: I meant edit your question and post it there, not post it in the comments.

Comment: @sashoalm ~> :| OK. got it!

Comment: Btw, how come your project doesn't depend on any external lib, I thought you use dfxlib in it?

Comment: @sashoalm : I added its source files and headers to my project.

Comment: First I checked it with linking the dxflib.lib to my project and then I tried to compile the source files with my project. None of them worked !

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to write all of the virtual functions as you did with below:

```
void CreatorAdaptor::addLine(const DL_LineData &d){
     // something something
}
```

You may left empty them but you must define them because they are defined as virtual functions in the dxf library. Of course, the other option is to delete all of virtual function definitions in the CreatorAdaptor class.